# best way to add additional fields to django-rest-framework ModelViewSet when create

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Book model with a foreign key to user (the owner of the book):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForiegnKey(User)
    ...
```

I've created a ModelViewSet for Book which shows the books owned by the logged in user:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Book
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Now to create a new book, I want to save user field with request.user, not with data sent from the rest client (for more security). for example:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.DATA['user'] = request.user
    ... (some code to create new Book from request.DATA using serialize class)
```

but I got this error:
This QueryDict instance is immutable. (means request.DATA is a immutable QueryDict and can't  be changed)

Do you know any better way to add additional fields when creating an object with django rest framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**: Since v3 you need to do this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

The principle remains the same.

---

You want to make the `owner` field of your book serializer read-only and then set the association with the user in `pre_save()`.

Something like:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.owner = self.request.user
```

See the [tutorial section on "Associating Snippets with Users"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Just pass read_only=True. See http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments

Comment: I use a ModelSerializer and the fields are defined implicitly from model fields.

Comment: I did it using related fields:

owner = serializers.RelatedField()

thanks for your help

Comment: No worries. I was going to suggest you have a read here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-which-fields-should-be-read-only — Good luck with your project.

Comment: the pre_save method is not valid anymore in the django rest 3.0 and above

Comment: clarification: the [create](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18) method, which calls `perform_create`, does validation first, so if `owner` is a required field (as per the question), this would fail?

Comment: read-only fields are excluded from serialiser validation. (unless there's a unique together constraint...)

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth this has changed in [Django REST Framework 3](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/). There is now a `perform_create()` that replaces the older `pre_save()` and `post_save()` hooks suggested in a previous answer. For example:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Hope this saves someone some time.

Comment: Awesome.  Just a minor typo, it should be `def perform_create(self, serializer):`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ModelSerializer` it's as easy as implementing the `restore_object()` method:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):

        create = not instance
        instance = super(MySerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)

        if create:
            instance.user = self.context['request'].user

        return instance

    # ...
```

`restore_object()` is used to deserialize a dictionary of attributes into an object instance. `ModelSerializer` [implements this method](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L924) and creates/updates the instance for the model you specified in the `Meta` class. If the given `instance` is `None` it means the object still has to be created. In this case you just set the `user` field with the desired value.

More information:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#declaring-serializers