# How to make change in request.data keeping check on serializer validataion in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I am making quiz app which has following structure

```
class UserQuizRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userrecord')
    score = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
```

I have serializer class of it

```
class UserQuizRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserQuizRecord
        fields = ('user', 'quiz','score')
```

Here is the views.py file and the detail route I am providing with data `{quiz:1,score:7}` I wish to add user to the request.data or serializer at in the views function. I am failing to get the right way to do it.

```
class QuizView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
    model = Quiz

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[AllowAny], url_path='rank')
    def rank(self, request, pk=None):
        request.data.quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = UserQuizRecordSerializer(data = request.data )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            rank = UserQuizRecord.objects.filter(Q(quiz=request.data.quiz.id),Q(score__gte=request.data.score)).count()
            return Response({'rank':rank}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What is the best way to perform this operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to add additional fields to django-rest-framework ModelViewSet when create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571157/best-way-to-add-additional-fields-to-django-rest-framework-modelviewset-when-cre)

Comment: @YasinBahtiyar But that answer doesn't go into checking the validity of serializer after adding user field.

Comment: I want to carry the serializer save operation in views.py file